# BigQuery: Unrecognized name for derived field

Tags: google-bigquery

I've 2 tables 1&2. Inside table1, I've created a derived field "actualoutput" against which I'm using join with table-2 with "newgroup" as a connector, to get field "finalgroup" as shown below.

Since the derived field cannot be used in the same select, I used foll. query by using the derived field in the outer query. But this is giving error:

> Unrecognised name: actualoutput

The query:

```
select source, detail, CONCAT(IFNULL(source, ''), "-", IFNULL(detail, '')) AS actualoutput, newgroup, finalgroup 
from (
SELECT source, detail from `table1`)
left join (select newgroup,finalgroup from `table2`)
on actualoutput=newgroup
```

Refer image: columns highlighted in yellow are used as a key.

[image]

Can someone please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. Basically I was using incorrect query by using table-2 columns in the same outerquery along with derived field "actualoutput". Foll. query gives output as expected:

```
select source, detail, CONCAT(IFNULL(Source, ''), "-", IFNULL(Detail, '')) AS actualoutput, newgroup,finalgroup
from (
select source, detail, CONCAT(IFNULL(Source, ''), "-", IFNULL(Detail, '')) AS actualoutput
from (
SELECT source, detail from `table1`))
left join (select newgroup,finalgroup from `table2`)
on actualoutput=newgroup
```

Comment: With this query you also select `newgroup` column which is not present in the "Final Table" in your image (and identical with "actualoutput" column). A simpler version could be: 

select source, detail, actualoutput, finalgroup
from (select source, detail, CONCAT(IFNULL(Source, ''), "-", IFNULL(Detail, '')) AS actualoutput
from `mydataset.table1`)
left join `mydataset.table2`
on actualoutput=newgroup;